# Is there any way to synchronise a few number of cy.wait functions/

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, promise, async-await, cypress

I am working on a cypress test which dynamically creates a few number of routes. A general example of that is as follows:

```
export const checkAndLoadApis = (apis, pageUrl) => {
  let allResponses = [];
  cy.server();
  cy.log(apis)
  apis.forEach((api, index) => {
    // Alias creation for API request
    cy.route(api).as('route'+Object.keys(api)[0]);
    cy.wait('route'+Object.keys(api)[0])
      .then(apiRes => {
        expect(apiRes.status).eq(200);
        allResponses[index] = apiRes;
    })
  });
  cy.visit(pageUrl);
  return allResponses;
}
```

the response value is clearly null, because the code runs asynchronously.
Could anybody help me to improve the code please? Using promises or async/await structure seems difficult in cypress code.

Comment: response is defined at the second line. It should be returned at the end of the function.

Comment: at line 5, it was previously "apis.foreach((api, index)", which I forgot to add "index" in the version I copied to stackoverflow.

Comment: It doesn't give any error. The problem was that the returned value was always null. So, I started applying promises or async/await in this structure. So far, I couldn't find any good way to apply them.

Comment: That's exactly correct. Sorry, I copied and pasted very fast. There were many additional code and I got rid of them very fast.